# Removing a specific colored lines from a picture

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, image-processing

In the image shown below, there a two colored lines (blue and black), I want to know the process of removing either blue or black colored lines. I am new to image processing, is there any process using Matlab or Python for detecting and removing specific colored lines.

[image]

Comment: you can look into openCV for python.

Comment: I can second `OpenCV` it runs very quickly. It may also go by the import name `cv2`. It is also common in `OpenCV` to use a BGR (Blue, Green, Red) ordering to be mindful of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In MATLAB:

Not sure how much fidelity you need but this is a method of preserving only the blue uses rudimentary techniques including thresholding. Using a base blue colour defined in `rgb-coordinates` as `rgb(0,0,255)`. By evaluating if a pixel does not have the colour content that is similar to our base blue colour. We can find the differences between each colour channel of our image and base blue colour then set the pixels to white if it does not fit the condition. White will be set by changing the pixel to `rgb(255,255,255)`. In MATLAB layer 1 of the image is the red channel, layer 2 is the green channel and layer 3 is the blue channel. Below I use a set of for-loops to scan through the image. There are more concise ways of doing this but this way method seems to go through the fundamentals.
[image: RGB Layers]

### Removing Black Pixels

[image: Blue Lines Image]

```
%Reading in the image%
Image = imread("Image.png");
[Image_Height,Image_Width,Number_Of_Colour_Channels] = size(Image);
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(Image);

%Defining a blue pixel base%
Red_Content = 0;
Green_Content = 0;
Blue_Content = 255;

Red_Channel = 1;
Green_Channel = 2;
Blue_Channel = 3;

Red_Threshold = 100;
Green_Threshold = 100;
Blue_Threshold = 230;

for Row_Scanner = 1: Image_Height
   for Column_Scanner = 1: Image_Width 
    
    Red_Value = Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner,Red_Channel);
    Green_Value = Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner,Green_Channel);
    Blue_Value = Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner,Blue_Channel);
    
    if(Blue_Value < Blue_Threshold || Green_Value > Green_Threshold || Red_Value > Red_Threshold)
        Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner,1) = 255; 
        Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner,2) = 255; 
        Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner,3) = 255; 
    end    
   end
end

subplot(1,2,2); imshow(Image);
```

### Removing Blue Pixels

[image: Black Lines Image]

```
%Reading in the image%
Image = imread("Image.png");
[Image_Height,Image_Width,Number_Of_Colour_Channels] = size(Image);
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(Image);

%Defining a blue pixel base%
Red_Content = 0;
Green_Content = 0;
Blue_Content = 255;

Red_Channel = 1;
Green_Channel = 2;
Blue_Channel = 3;

Red_Threshold = 240;
Green_Threshold = 240;
Blue_Threshold = 100;

for Row_Scanner = 1: Image_Height
   for Column_Scanner = 1: Image_Width 
    
    Red_Value = Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner,Red_Channel);
    Green_Value = Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner,Green_Channel);
    Blue_Value = Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner,Blue_Channel);
    
    if(~(Blue_Value < Blue_Threshold || Green_Value > Green_Threshold || Red_Value > Red_Threshold))
        Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner,1) = 255; 
        Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner,2) = 255; 
        Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner,3) = 255; 
    end      
   end
end

subplot(1,2,2); imshow(Image);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thank you very much, I greatly appreciate your help

Comment: No problem, happy to help! :)